# Will libraries in requirements.txt install its own dependencies?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a `requirements.txt` for my project.

I got the file with `pip freeze > requirements.txt` but I have some questions about it.

Basically I have a ton of libraries on my PC, so I only want the ones for my project in `requirements.txt`.

If for example, I remove all libraries from the file and only leave `awscli`, will `awscli` dependencies install when the user runs `pip install -r requirements.txt`? Or will I need to keep every dependency of every library inside the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will. However, based on your question, I assume you need to familiarize yourself with a concept called [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Comment: Is it recommended to replicate the program in a VE and then freeze that project?

Comment: Yes, basically each separate python project should have it's own virtual environment, so that you always have exactly the libraries and modules that you need, no less, no more. That way it's a lot easier to manage them.